# Flask/mysql - not returning records added after mysql connection established

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I'm building a simple flask app, with a single route which retrieves values from a small mysql db, and displays them nicely in a graph in the browser.

A new record is added to the mysql db by a separate service every 10 seconds (and I have logged into mysql directly and confirmed that these rows are being inserted as expected), and my flask app will graph just the values added in the past minute.

When I start my flask app, it initially looks good; the values from the past 1 minute show nicely.  However, with subsequent browser refreshes, the number of values being shown reduces.  This is because values are getting older and falling out of the 1 minute window, and the latest values are not being included, i.e. my query is not returning any db rows that were added to the db after the flask app has started and the mysql connection is established.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)

mysql = MySQL()
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'test'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'test_db'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
mysql.init_app(app)

db_conn = mysql.connect()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    cursor = db_conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT created_at, loudness FROM readings WHERE created_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 second);")
    data = cursor.fetchall()

    labels, values = format_data(data)
    return render_template("graph.html", labels=labels, values=values)

def format_data(data):
  labels = []
  values = []
  for created_at, loudness in data:
    labels.append(created_at.strftime("%d/%m %H:%M"))
    values.append(loudness)
  
  return labels, values
```

If I restart the flask app, the latest values again display nicely.  Anybody know why values added to the db after the flask app has started aren't being returned?

Making the connection inside the index route, rather that than outside of it, fixes the issue, but that doesn't seem to be how these mysql packages are designed to be used in flask...

The code above uses the flask_mysql package, but I've tried the mysql.connector package too, and it behaves the same way.

I've also tried whittling my query down to its most basic form, (`SELECT created_at, loudness FROM readings;`), but it's still not getting the latest values, so the problem isn't query-related.

Comment: Transaction isolation: you have a single connection, so it starts a transaction when the app is started. Data added by other transactions won't be visible unless you commit or roll back the flask db connection.  (If your app is only `SELECT`ing you could also consider using the connection in autocommit  mode)

Comment: Just to add to the above: default transaction isolation levelin mysql is repeatable read in which non-blocking reads do not see changes done by subsequent transactions. I would make the connection in the routes, not outside of it.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I don't have a MySQL setup to test an approach properly and I cannot find a good dupe. I would invite you to answer this if you could. I can give an SQLA answer but that's not the same thing....

Comment: @roganjosh tbh I think there will be a duplicate somewhere, but it would be nice if the OP were to confirm the theory.

Comment: Thanks @snakecharmerb; that makes sense.  Just did some testing and both your suggestions work nicely.  The autocommit is tidy so will go with that I think.  Happy to accept this as an answer.

Comment: Thanks @Shadow for the additional context; was super helpful.

Comment: And thanks @roganjosh, just for getting involved :)